# How do I build an ServiceStack.Host.Mvc project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, servicestack

I'm trying to test out ServiceStack for an MVC 4 App in VS2012:

- I start a new project, choose empty MVC4.
- Using the package manager I install the MVC Power Pack `(PM> Install-Package ServiceStack.Host.Mvc)`

However I immediately get the following 3 errors on build even after following the special instructions for MvC.

- > The non-generic method 'ServiceStack.ContainerTypeExtensions.Register(Funq.Container, object, System.Type)' cannot be used with type arguments
- > Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'ServiceStack.Data.IDbConnectionFactory' because it is not a delegate type
- > The name 'SqlServerDialect' does not exist in the current context

They're all related to the following code in `AppHost.cs`

```cs
// Requires ConnectionString configured in Web.Config
var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AppDb"].ConnectionString;
container.Register<IDbConnectionFactory>(c =>
    new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(connectionString, SqlServerDialect.Provider));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That code is not being used by any of the example services so you can just comment it out, e.g:

```
//container.Register<IDbConnectionFactory>(c =>
//    new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(connectionString, SqlServerDialect.Provider));
```

---

### Using OrmLite in ServiceStack

But if you want to use SqlServer with ServiceStack's OrmLite you can install it from NuGet:

```
PM> Install-Package ServiceStack.OrmLite.SqlServer
```

#### Using an alternative RDBMS

Otherwise you can install your preferred RDBMS solution, e.g. for PostgreSQL, install:

```
PM> Install-Package ServiceStack.OrmLite.PostgreSQL
```

And you would change it to use the PostgreSQL provider, e.g:

```
container.Register<IDbConnectionFactory>(c =>
    new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(connectionString, PostgreSqlDialect.Provider));
```

#### Querying your database inside ServiceStack Services and Razor Views

You can then use the **Db** database inside your services or razor views like:

In your AppHost:

```
using (var db = container.Resolve<IDbConnectionFactory>().Open()) {
    Db.CreateTableIfNotExists<TestDb>();
}
```

Use **Db** property in your ServiceStack services (or Razor Views):

```
public object Any(TestDb request)
{
    Db.Insert(request);
    return Db.SingleById<TestDb>(request.Id);
}
```

*TestDb can be any POCO, Request DTO, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Check to make sure the dependency packages are in your references and using'ed as necessary.

```
  <dependency id="WebActivator" version="1.5" />
  <dependency id="ServiceStack.Mvc" version="4.0" />
  <dependency id="ServiceStack.Server" version="4.0" />
  <dependency id="ServiceStack.OrmLite.SqlServer" version="4.0" />
```

List pulled from https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/NuGet/ServiceStack.Host.Mvc/servicestack.host.mvc.nuspec

Comment: I updated all remaining ASP MVC packages and the error "The name 'SqlServerDialect' does not exist in the current context" went away. Not sure why.